# Javascript Jest Unit Test Time Interval

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

i need some help with the Unittest for my Time Intervals.
Maybe someone can tell me how it works? I am new with writing Unit Test..
An example would be great.

Here is my Code i want to Test:

```
export const dayIntervalFromDate = (date) => {
  const fromDate = new Date(date);
  fromDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  const toDate = new Date(date);
  toDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
  return { from: fromDate, to: toDate };
}
```

**dayIntervalFromDate Test**

```
    it("returns day interval from date", () => {
        const mockDayInterval = new Date('2021-01-01');
        const expectedFrom = new Date('2021-01-01');
        expectedFrom.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        const expectedTo = new Date('2021-01-01');
        expectedTo.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

        jest.fn(() => mockDayInterval);
      
        const { from , to } = dayIntervalFromDate(Date);
  
        expect(from).toEqual(expectedFrom);
        expect(to).toEqual(expectedTo);
    });
```

[image: failed]

Comment: This isn't a test-writing service; what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: it("returns day interval from date", () => {
        const dayIntervalFrom = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0);
        dayIntervalFrom.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        const from = dayIntervalFromDate;

        const dayIntervalTo = new Date(23, 59, 59, 999);
        dayIntervalTo.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
        const to = dayIntervalTo;


        expect(dayIntervalFromDate(Date)).toHaveBeenCalledWith(from, to);
    });

Comment: _"...and what exactly is the problem with it?"_ - does it pass, fail, crash, ...?

Comment: i have update my Question

Comment: Does `dayIntervalFromDate(Date)` make sense? That's passing the _class_, not an instance. Also it's unclear how `jest.fn(() => mockDayInterval)` is supposed to connect to anything else that's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this now...

```
    it("returns day interval from date", () => {
        const mockDayInterval = new Date();
        const expectedFrom = new Date();
        expectedFrom.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        const expectedTo = new Date();
        expectedTo.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

        jest.fn(() => mockDayInterval);
      
        const { from , to } = dayIntervalFromDate(new Date());
  
        expect(from).toEqual(expectedFrom);
        expect(to).toEqual(expectedTo);
    });
```

[image: pass]